# Is there a name for symmetric matrices with exactly one non-zero eigenvalue which also equals the trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Specifically, matrices of this form.

In 2 dimensions:

\begin{bmatrix}
a^2 &  ab\\
ab & b^2
\end{bmatrix}

In 3 dimensions:

\begin{bmatrix}
a^2 &  ab & ac\\
ab & b^2 & bc \\
ac & bc & c^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Thank you!

Comment: Symmetric rank one matrices?

Answer (score 1):

just called rank one symmetric. There is a nonzero column vector $v$  so that your matrix is
$$ v v^T $$
For any column vector $w$ orthogonal to $v,$ we get $v v^T w = v(v^Tw) = 0$
while the nonzero eigenvalue comes from $v v^T v = v |v|^2,$  and the nonzero eigenvalue is $|v|^2 = v \cdot v$

Comment: How about $diag(-1,0,0)$?

Comment: @JCAA alright, throw in $\alpha v v^T,$ seems both trace and eigenvalue come out $\alpha |v|^2$

Comment: I guess one needs to prove that there are no other solutions.